# javascript function does not work with passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am just starting with javascript.  I want to modify a simple counter code to let it accept parameter when the count() function is called.  But it just does not work.  Please help.  Thanks.

```
const clickEl = document.querySelector("#click");
const resetEl = document.querySelector("#reset");
const h1El = document.querySelector("h1");

var counts = 0;
if (localStorage.getItem("counts") !== NaN) {
    counts = localStorage.getItem("counts");
    h1El.innerHTML = `${counts}`;
} 

clickEl.addEventListener("click", count(1));
resetEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    counts = 0;
    localStorage.setItem("counts", counts);
    h1El.innerHTML = `${counts}`;
});
setInterval(count(3), 1000);

function count(n) {
    counts += n;
    localStorage.setItem("counts", counts);
    h1El.innerHTML = `${counts}`;
}
```

Comment: the event handlers need to be functions, not the result of calling functions - example, `count(1)` calls the function ... `() => count(1)` IS a function

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the code to  the following and they work now.  

clickEl.addEventListener("click", () => count(1));

setInterval(() => count(3), 1000);

Comment: well, there is a better way ... the correct way ... setInterval expects a function as an argument, and you're providing the result of calling the function ... same deal as with the event handler

Comment: Just found out there is an even simpler way.  setInterval(count, 1000, 3);

Comment: yes, there is that - not many people know that